# How to clone ImageSpan

Tags: android

How to clone imagespan.

I want to use setspan() with one imagespan twice.

```
    ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(this,R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    String tx = "dfsfsfsfsfsdfsdfs";
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(tx);
    ss.setSpan(is,0,1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(CharacterStyle.wrap(is),6,7, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tv.setText(ss);
```

but the CharacterStyle.wrap is not working for imagespan.

Thank you for answering.

Comment: Basically, you can't, and the reason for that is arguably a bug in the framework. When ultimately drawn, `ImageSpan`s are treated as `ReplacementSpan`s; i.e., `ImageSpan`s are found by obtaining the `ReplacementSpan`s from a `Spanned` sequence. However, when you `wrap()` an `ImageSpan`, it's treated as a `MetricAffectingSpan` – the superclass of `ReplacementSpan` – and is wrapped in a different `MetricAffectingSpan` subclass, so when the draw routine looks for `ReplacementSpan`s, it does not get any of the wrapped `ImageSpan`s, and they're simply ignored. Nice, eh?

Comment: Actually, I shouldn't have said "you can't". I just meant that you can't with `CharacterStyle.wrap()`. You could certainly create your own wrapper class, from a descendant of `ReplacementSpan`; e.g., https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Vxeh5yeHYy7VK65j1g3xSDh-Z5wOJDK/view?usp=drivesdk, which seems to work just fine, in my quick tests.

Comment: @MikeM.
I tried it, it is ok, it is very helpful to me, thank you for your answer!